# jquery ajax content not loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just trying to load a simple html page with ajax.

```
$("h1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.html',
    success: function(response) {
            $('#buttonGroups').html(response);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
})
```

But I never get the alert..? What am I missing?

Comment: Did it hit the server? did the request was successful? You didn't give too much info you know.

Comment: Sorry.. yes it gets a 200 status and it clears the content in that element..

Comment: Just solved it.. I was missing "dataType:'html'," :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the response as an HTML so you need tell that to jquery:

```
$("h1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.html',
    dataType: "html",   // <====
    success: function(response) {
            $('#buttonGroups').html(response);
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
});
```